# Horizontal Table aligning not working

Tags: html, css, html-table

Suppose I have some code like so...

```css
table {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see the text is not centering so far. However, when I add this code it is centering.

```
td {
  width: 1000px;
}
```

Can anyone explain me the reason why it is doing so?

Also, I do not want my code to be of specified `height`s and `width`s(in pixels), so can anyone explain how to align the text horizontally without including a specified width and height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not centering because you do not have a specified height to your `td`s and when you do, you find your code working. If the `td` width is `1000px` it is going to make your text go down `500px` down the page.

And to answer the second part of your question, here are two ways you can solve the problem.

## 1.

```css
table {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

## 2.

```css
table {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for, now I have 2 ways to do it.

Answer (score 2):

```css
table {
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<table onclick="this.style.width = '100%'">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This might help you see that the text is indeed centered, but the table is not expanding to the screen. Clicking the table will set the `width` to `100%`, and will produce your expected output.

Comment: This is a very nice answer you gave, might modify my table like this, but all I was just looking for was how to center align the text in my table when it loaded.

Comment: @Ryan My point was that fortunately, you have already centered the text with `text-align: center`, but it is relative to the `td` element, not the page. This solution and the one by Yash both simply give examples as to how to orient the `table` to produce this effect.